# Caching many AJAX database writes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, zend-framework

I'm building a web based photo and text editor. The problem that I'm running in to is best illustrated by an example:

The user can select a color for their text. The color is selected by dragging a slider, so changes like 100 times per second. The color of the text has to be updated in the database. Rather than performing 100 writes per second, I've built it like this: after 3 seconds of **not** sliding, the database is updated.

The user can also view an example of their 'page'. That example is generated purely by html and css, which it reads from the database. But if the user tries to view his example **within 3 seconds** of changing the text color, he sees the wrong color in the example.

Does anybody have a good idea of handling a problem like this? I was thinking about caching somehow, but I don't have a lot of experience with that and can't picture the solution yet.

I'm using Zend Framework and jQuery.

Comment: update database when drag ends

Comment: @Vytautas has the solution here. If you post your code we can give you guidance on how to implement it.

Comment: Do you have 3 sliders (RGB), or just one? If you only have one - i would do it on focusOut - so when they press anywhere else it will be saved. Else i would create a update button for the colors, but i could imagine that's what you are trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 1):

3 seconds is a pretty long time in UI design, so maybe you should rethink your architecture here.

Is the slider JQuery UI? If it is you could just bind the database call to the "slidechange" event of the slider to make sure the user has stopped sliding.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#events

Maybe you should also consider building the example page based on the values in the input form instead of values from the database. Even if you make the database call it could (theoretically) not have finished updating the value in the database before the example page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it so that changing things throws "persistance" events that are queued up sent to the server when:

- the user hits a save button
- the user goes to preview his changes
- after x seconds.

So if the user makes 1,2 or 22 changes  quickly they are queued up and then are sent all at once (the backend could then also be smart enough to ignore 3 of 4 reudant "change color" events and persist only the latest one).